# Can't get dataProvider object outside of QGIS python Interpreter

Tags: qgis, python

Within PyCharm

```
import qgis.core as qgis
vector_lyr = qgis.QgsVectorLayer("Point", "distance nodes", "memory")
pr = vector_lyr.dataProvider()
print pr
prints None
```

Within Python Interpreter in QGIS

```
import qgis.core as qgis
vector_lyr = qgis.QgsVectorLayer("Point", "distance nodes", "memory")
pr = vector_lyr.dataProvider()
print pr
prints <qgis.core.QgsVectorDataProvider object at 0x000000000DAFF0D0>
```

I've tried this [Getting dataProvider from vector layer outside QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46714/getting-dataprovider-from-vector-layer-outside-qgis) and still no luck. Thanks.

[Edit] I found this: [Access Sextante (processing) in standalone QGIS app?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71820/access-sextante-processing-in-standalone-qgis-app) is this the case for dataProviders? Is there a workaround?

[EDIT2]

Tried this to no avail. I'm trying to create an in memory vector layer, write values to it then do something else after.

```
import qgis.core as qgis

qgis.QgsApplication.initQgis()

vector_lyr = qgis.QgsVectorLayer("Point", "distance nodes", "memory")
pr = vector_lyr.dataProvider()
print pr
prints None
```

Comment: You need to do a few things before you can access layers.  One of the main things it to initQGis with data providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by following what Nathan W said (thank you Nathan) about adding this code:

```
QgsApplication.initQgis().
```

As well as having to set:

```
qgishome = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\\' to r'C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\\'.
```

This bit of code was useful for debugging.

```
QgsApplication.initQgis()

providers = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList()
for provider in providers:
    print provider

print QgsApplication.showSettings()
```

When ran on qgis-dev it had only one provider. While qgis path had many more, so I stuck this the one that had more.

I then had to set an windows environment variable for GDAL_DATA to

```
"C:\OSGeo4W64\share\epsg_csv"
```

After restarting the interpreter everything was working as it should.

Answer (score 3):

You need to first initQgis so that the data providers are loaded:

```
from qgis.core import QgsApplication
QgsApplication.initQgis()
... your stuff here
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the System has changed a bit since the answers of 2014.  Only calling

> QgsApplication.initQgis()

without first Setting up the QgsApplication can crash Python in the current Version (2.14 LTR).  I was successful in using the following code at the top of my script:

> ```
> qgs = QgsApplication(sys.argv, False)
> qgs.setPrefixPath(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis-ltr", True)
> qgs.initQgis()
> ```

Comment: This does not work for the current LTR 2.18.23.