# QgsRasterLayer is invalid when run as standalone PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, layers, standalone, validation

The following code behaves as I expect when I run it in QGIS Python Console, but when I run it as a standalone from the console, the layer is invalid.

```py
urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0'
raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'OpenStreetMap', 'wms')
l = raster_layer

                        #==stand alone==#==QGIS Console===
print(l.isValid())      # False         # True
print(l.dataProvider()) # None          # QgsRasterDataProvider<>
print(l.providerType()) # "wms"         # "wms"
print(l.rasterType())   # 0             # 3
```

What do I need to set up for stand alone script to be successful with adding Open Street Maps to my project.

**Complete code below**

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject, \
    QgsRasterLayer, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, \
    QgsRectangle, QgsMapRendererParallelJob
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas, QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge

crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem("EPSG:3857")

#### APPLICATION ####
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/bin/qgis", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
qgs.initQgis()

#### PROJECT ####
proj = QgsProject.instance()
proj.setCrs(crs)
root = proj.layerTreeRoot()

#### CANVAS ####
canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(proj.layerTreeRoot(), canvas)
canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.red)
canvas.setDestinationCrs(crs)
extent = QgsRectangle(1042595, 7522132,1131975, 7536048)
canvas.setExtent(extent)
canvas.refresh()
canvas.update()
mapSettings = canvas.mapSettings()
mapSettings.setOutputSize( QSize(800,800) )

#### LAYERS ####
urlWithParams = 'type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0'
raster_layer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'OpenStreetMap', 'wms')
proj.addMapLayer(raster_layer)
assert raster_layer.isValid()
canvas.setLayers([raster_layer])

#### RENDERING ####
job = QgsMapRendererParallelJob(mapSettings)
job.start()
job.waitForFinished()
image = job.renderedImage()
image.save('foo.png')
proj.write('foo.qgz')
```

**Environment**

The Python path looks slightly different for the two cases, but I believe they are essentially running the same environment. The following code produced the exact same output.

```py
import sys, qgis, qgis.core
print(sys.version) # 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) [GCC 9.4.0]
print(qgis.__file__) # /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/qgis/__init__.py
print(qgis.core.Qgis.QGIS_VERSION) # 3.24.3-Tisler
```

Comment: Do you have the same environment as QGIS when you run the python interpreter?

Comment: @AndreasMüller: I have added a section; "Environment". Please let me know if there are more details you need.

Comment: Have you set a GDAL_DATA environnement variable ? At start, QGIS sets different environnement variables so if they are missing, your code in standalone won't work. On my configuration, your code works perfectly.

Comment: I'm on windows, but you should start python with the same environment (variables) than qgis uses. There is probably a shell script to start qgis you can use as a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After learning how ([source](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/432870/getting-details-about-why-a-layer-is-invalid)), I set my code to print the error message associated with the layer being invalid:

```
if not raster_layer.isValid():
    print("error summary:", raster_layer.error().summary())
assert raster_layer.isValid()
```

And the resulting error summary was:

```
"Cannot instantiate the 'wms' data provider"
```

So I googled for this problem and found this Q&A ([Can't get dataProvider object outside of QGIS python Interpreter](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97642/cant-get-dataprovider-object-outside-of-qgis-python-interpreter)).

In the end I simply had to use a different prefix path. And after that the same data providers were available in the stand alone as within QGIS, and now it the layer was valid.

```
QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr", True) # instead of /usr/bin/qgis
```

**More details**

I set my code to also print the available data providers:

```
if not raster_layer.isValid():
    print("error summary:", raster_layer.error().summary())
from qgis.core import QgsProviderRegistry
print("providers: ", QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerList())
assert raster_layer.isValid()
```

The results, when prefix path was "/usr/bin/python" were:

- QGIS Python Console: `['DB2', 'OAPIF', 'WFS', 'arcgisfeatureserver', 'arcgismapserver', 'delimitedtext', 'ept', 'gdal', 'geonode', 'gpx', 'grass', 'grassraster', 'hana', 'mdal', 'memory', 'mesh_memory', 'mssql', 'ogr', 'pdal', 'postgres', 'postgresraster', 'spatialite', 'vectortile', 'virtual', 'virtualraster', 'wcs', 'wms']`
- standalone script / shell: `['ept', 'gdal', 'memory', 'mesh_memory', 'ogr', 'vectortile']`