# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dataProvider'

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, attribute-table

I want to add new column to attribute table of vector layer via Python console. I'm trying to do this following instructions from http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html.
But while defying caps

```py
caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
```

I'm getting error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dataProvider'

I've found some solutions referring to setting up QGIS Python environment correctly. ([Getting dataProvider from vector layer outside QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46714/getting-dataprovider-from-vector-layer-outside-qgis)). But this solution crash my QGIS.

Any idea what should I do to access (?) (or rather 'get?') dataProvider?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @antonio! How did you define your `layer` and which QGIS version are you using?

Comment: As for now I want to add the column to active layer in project, so: 

`layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()`

QGIS version: 2.12

Comment: Are you wanting to add a new column inside QGIS or outside?

Comment: Inside. (But I'm not sure if I understand this question corectly.) I want to add the column to existing attribute table of activeLayer. Like via GUI: open attribute table -> start editing -> add new column -> set name, type, etc. -> done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following to add a new field and determining its type:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
layer.startEditing()
layer.dataProvider().addAttributes( [ QgsField("Name", QVariant.String) ] )
layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works perfectly and does exactly what I need.

Comment: @antonio - Awesome buddy! Glad it works :)